# Animate dropped object when dragged object comes near to it like message bubble in Facebook messenger and its cross mark in Android

Tags: android

Animate dropped object when dragged object comes near to it like message bubble in Facebook messenger and its cross mark in Android. I searched it but did not find any exact solution.Like in images a Facebook messenger bubble is open now if I move it in right,left or up direction a cross mark appears and animate in the direction of bubbles movement.
for now I have implemented drag and drop functionality. For my scenario I have to move an image to a trash like basket. so my image is dragged object and trash basket is dropped object.
[image: Image-1 Up direction][image: Image-1 Left direction][image: Image-1 Right direction]

Comment: use simple ObjectAnimator/ValueAnimator

Comment: @pskink any link or example of objectAnimator  with dragand drop